# SELECT e From Employee e -- why a redundant "e"?

Tags: java, jpa, syntax, jpql

[Sample](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF) query:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE SUBSTRING(e.name, 3) = 'Mac'
```

In this syntax, it seems intuitive to say `SELECT e`, that `e` is now declared or defined(?).  However, isn't the second `e`: `FROM Employee e` redundant?

This is a throwback or similarity to [SQL SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)?

Comment: To *what* would the `e` in `SELECT e` *refer to*, if it doesn't occur elsewhere in the query? It's not the name of anything.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever why isn't the syntax like so: `SELECT e FROM employee WHERE ...`?  I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: With your proposed syntax - why introduce `e` at all? Why would it not be `SELECT FROM employee...`? - what purpose is the `e` serving in your hypothetical example? Whereas, in the original query, the `e` in the `SELECT` clause is referring to the `employee` entity in the `FROM` clause that was assigned the alias `e`.

Answer (score 4):

The second `e` is a [*identification variable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbuj). It actually defines `e` by telling the JPQL parser that you are using `e` somewhere else in your query, and that it refers to the `Employee` entity. The first occurrence of `e` is where you usa that `e`.

So, it's not redundant. If you leave out the first one, the JPQL parser doesn't know what to select. If you leave it out the second time, you're selecting something that the JPQL parser doesn't know.

Answer (score 3):

JPQL syntax is a little different with normal SQL syntax.According to your sample,first e is represent * of normal SQL. So it is not redundant. But you use JPA 2.x, using criteria query is more better than JPQL

Comment: right, I guess it's more of a SQL question then Java question per se.  Poorly asked question in that I've conflated two differing syntax questions for different languages.

Comment: Yes may be you can remove 'sql' tag so that it avoids confusion. My answer is wrong in this context then

Comment: Critera has a different scope than JPQL; it is in no way a general replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question with the same concerns as you are. I noticed that when you **select *** the results comes in columns, and when you **select e** there's only one column with some kind of serialized entities as results. So I found a pretty good explanation about this at http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/03/17/jpa-select-clause/

---

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e
```

This is quite similar to SQL, the difference is:

- This query does not return a set of records from columns, instead it
  returns an entity.
- This entity is aliased to e , it is called as
  identification variable.
- This identification variable is tied to
  Employee type and it means result will be an entity of  Employee 
  type.

Answer (score 0):

use "e." (which columns you have)

```
  SELECT e.name, e.e FROM Employee e WHERE SUBSTRING(e.name, 3) = 'Mac'
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no need to use the second e in this case (yes it is redundant) if you have single query like this. It makes sense when you join two tables and if those two tables have common column names then you would select each  column using that table alias 'e'

Comment: Apart from the fact that the JPA spec defines the syntax for JPQL and that identification variable is mandatory.

Comment: OOPs MY Bad it is JPQL. :( Yes @ DataNucleus you are right. `Although the SELECT and WHERE clauses can reference identification variables, they cannot declare them. All identification variables must be declared in the FROM clause`

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This only works with Hibernate as JPA implementation since this information corresponds to HQL.

In this simple case you don't have to use the `e` (which is nothing more than an alias). Since you are selecting the complete entity, you even don't have to write the `select e` part. So you can write:

```
FROM Employee WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 3) = 'Mac'
```

Explanation:

- In the `from` part, you specify for which Entities you are looking for. The `e` behind the `Employee` is just an alias for `Employee` which you can use to address the whole object (the `select` part) or attributes from it. In simple queries you don't need it, but as soon you have a join in your query, it's always a good idea to use an alias.
- The `select` part of the query is for selecting which attributes of an entity you want to get back. If you omit the ´select`part or just specify the alias (`e` in this case), JPA gives back the whole Entity. In SQL this does usually not work (at least for Oracle).

To answer your question in the comment: You can *use* the alias `e` in the `select` part of the query. But in Order to do so, you must teach JPA what this `e` refers to. And this is what the `from Employee e` part is doing.

Comment: That's HQL, not JPQL. http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select

Comment: You're right... I have never used another JPA implementation than Hibernate. And Hibernate allows ommitting the `from` part with the JPA-API so I thought it would apply for JPA, too. As I have just remembered, there is a property for Hibernate to obey strictly to the JPA rules: hibernate.query.jpaql_strict_compliance.

Comment: I found it helpful to have my IDE resp. the project configured to check for correct JPQL when transitioning from HQL. Helped a lot for me. Plus completions within JPQL strings are nice also.